# Two SQL statements that are same except for binding variable names - will they be parsed once or twice?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I understand that the following two SQL queries are not the same from database point of view and will be parsed twice by Oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = 'A';
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = 'B';
```

However, if I use binding variables, then the query is parsed once and will be reused for different values

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = :var
```

So, what will happen to the following two statements that are same except for the name of the binding variable?

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = :var1;
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN = :var2;
```

Are these statements considered equal? Or will it be parsed twice?

Comment: How would the system know they were the same without parsing them?

Comment: Are you asking because you want to prematurely optimize your system - or are you facing an actual, real, and impactful performance problem that you suspect is caused by the RDBMS treating the two queries separately and/or using different execution plans?

Comment: @Dai - it's the later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be treated differently in Oracle because query text has changed and hence it will treated as a new statement.

You can refer to below post for detailed understanding of binding variable and impact on hard/soft parsing.

[Post](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables)

Answer (score 0):

query with values and with place holders will be parsed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is open to some considerations.

### CURSOR_SHARING

Statements that are using literals can be treated as equal if CURSOR_SHARING is force to do so. The parameter CURSOR_SHARING determines what kind of SQL statements can share the same cursors.

- FORCE

> Forces statements that may differ in some literals, but are otherwise
> identical, to share a cursor, unless the literals affect the meaning
> of the statement.

- SIMILAR

> Causes statements that may differ in some literals, but are otherwise
> identical, to share a cursor, unless the literals affect either the
> meaning of the statement or the degree to which the plan is optimized.

- EXACT

> Only allows statements with identical text to share the same cursor.

Below I show you how two statements with literals are using the same cursor when CURSOR_SHARING is set to SIMILAR ( it will do the same with FORCE ). However, that entirely depends on the SQL statements themselves.

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(30) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> declare
begin
for i in 1 .. 100000
loop
insert into t values ( i , dbms_random.string('U','8'), dbms_random.string('U','20') ) ;
end loop;
commit;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SYS','T') ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> show parameter cursor_sharing

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
cursor_sharing                       string      SIMILAR

SQL> explain plan for select * from t where c1=100 ;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display) ;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    35 |   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |    35 |   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("C1"=100)

13 rows selected.

SQL> explain plan for select * from t where c1=9999 ;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display) ;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    35 |   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |    35 |   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("C1"=9999)

13 rows selected.
```

### **ADAPTIVE CURSOR SHARING**

Once you have statements that share the same cursor, like the ones you provided in your example, a new problem might appear. Cursors sharing the same plan will do so no matter what bind values are passed to the query. That could be a problem in different scenarios where changes in the bind values should have changes in plan due to cardinality estimation. Oracle 11g introduced for the first time the concept of **Adaptive Cursor Sharing** to solve this problem by allowing the server to compare the effectiveness of execution plans between executions with different bind variable values. If it notices suboptimal plans, it allows certain bind variable values, or ranges of values, to use alternate execution plans for the same statement. This functionality requires no additional configuration.

A SQL statement is subject to adaptive cursor sharing if the query is using bind variables and the CBD has determined that is bind aware.